# Room booking sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I have a problem in writing the sql to get the available rooms from the tables. my table structures are given below.

**table : booking**

```
booking_id    |    room_id   |    start_datetime  |   end_datetime    |   customer_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001           |     1        |  12-09-2012 2:35pm | 14-09-2012 9:00am |    23
002           |     2        | 10-09-2012 1:00am  | 20-09-2012 9:00am |    20
003           |     4        |  09-09-2012 1:35pm | 21-09-2012 9:00am |    43
004           |     1        |  22-09-2012 2:35pm | 24-09-2012 9:00am |    9
005           |     3        |  12-09-2012 9:00am | 13-09-2012 9:00am |    53
006           |     6        |  15-09-2012 9:00am | 19-09-2012 9:00am |    27
```

**Table : rooms**

contains the details about the rooms and the primary key of the table is room_id and it has 10 rooms from 1-10.

My problem is I want to know the rooms are available between 14-09-2012 6:00pm to 21-09-2012 9:00am which means I should only get the results of the room_id's as 1,3,5,7,8,9,10.

Can someone help me to write the SQL to get the available rooms from the above table structures.
 I'm using mysql as the database engine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it; *if there is a reservation that does not end before or start after* the reservation we want, the room is considered busy.

```
SELECT r.room_id
FROM rooms r
WHERE r.room_id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.room_id FROM bookings b
    WHERE NOT (b.end_datetime   < '2012-09-14T18:00'
               OR
               b.start_datetime > '2012-09-21T09:00'))
ORDER BY r.room_id;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3467a/5).